# creating banner slider shopify storefront api graphql

Tags: flutter, graphql, shopify, shopify-api, flutter-graphql

Hello Guys  i have  two question about  Shopify Storefront graphql api

Iam developing a flutter app based on shopify graphql api and  trying to create a carousel banner / Image Slider / Slideshow Images  inside the app but after long search  i couldnt figure out how and the shopify schema dont provide any query  for the banner or slideshow images  so how can i make banner slider in the app  if is not supported  is there any other way to achieve it

Other question  : how can i show categories and sub categories  for example this tree

T-Shirts-
-All
|
-Summer Sale
|
- Winter Sale - Up Cut Shirts
|
- Best Sales-
|
- Men
|
-Women

and so on

Comment: Did you get the solutions of these problems?I am currently building an app like this and experiencing same issues

Comment: ive figured out the solution ,  there is no banner actually but  the trick is you are getting the collection image as banner by collection